# IdentityServer and MVC clients foreign key relationship

Tags: identityserver3

I am working on setting up an IdentityServer(identityserver3) for different clients.

One question I have is that say my IdentityServer is hosted on its own server and has its own database. What is the best way for other MVC clients' database tables to create the foreign key relationship with the tables in identity server's database(user table).

Comment: The design you described here doesn't sound like good practice, why you want to give db access to your user table to clients? what are you try to achieve here?

Comment: suppose you have multiple web services in different servers, they may have their own DB, but the user who use these services are the same. In each service's DB, if I want to reference the user table, how should I do it. For example, get all items in services one belong to user 1.

Comment: @Ming there are several services already built, they all have their own db.  Now we need to integrate all of them. Since we want to add identity server to handle authentication and authorization for all of them, and we don't have time to redesign each clients. So we are facing this challenge, each client used to have their own user tables, since we moved and integrated all user tables to identity server, those clients lost the foreign key relationship to the user table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give identity table access to other clients, what you can do is to

1. Add your user metadata (from your user table) into token as claims, so that it can be read and utilzed in other MVC clients that have its own user data needs to join up.
2. or issue reference token if user metadata is too big to add to token, and clients can get additional user info by making call to [getUserInfo](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/userinfo.html) endpoint

Comment: what if in my MVC clients, I have a table which contains a column UserID, how do I add the foreign key relationship in this case?

Comment: @David you don't , what does your MVC client do? We are probably not on same page as I thought your MVC client should be just some sort of lookup service - select its own data based on userid comes in, if so, why you need to join the table?

Comment: the mvc client has its own businesslogic and database, I have multiple of them, they are written in different language php+mysql, c# mssql, java oracle etc. now I want to integrate all of them together, because all of them would have the same users after the integration but they were originally written by different team. Therefore i want to use identity server to provide a central Authentication & Authorization. so the challenge here is how to add foreign key relationship to the userID in identity server database for all clients' databse(mysql mssql oracle)

Comment: @David I don't think this is right approach that to resolve this issue relying on identityserver3, this is an integration issue cross multiple apps that holds same sort of user data graph, you need to resolve the data structure mess left from legacy systems by migrating them to one as far as  I understand before you can use central identity server

Comment: what if say everything is new, how would you design each mvc application. for example, I set up an identityserver, all user info is stored in identityserver's database. Now I am adding a new mvc application which has its own database and use identityserver for Auth. Now, say in my new MVC appliation, I created an itrem table which contains some item belong to certain user, so the table will have a UserID column. How do I add a foreign key relationship in this case since the item table and user table are in two different places.

Comment: @David you don't have to join tables in order to select data, there is nothing in database says you have to have a foreigner key before you can query the data, you can just set the userid as index field, can you not just do "select * from users when userid= 1234"?

Comment: What I want to do is select * from item where userID = 1 and item table is in mvc application